# certcontext is an invalid handle

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm trying to install a certificate into Trusted Root for Local machine.

This is what I have so far

```
  private void InstallCertificate()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
        string CertFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Resources\\cert.crt";
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(certificate);
        store.Close();
```

I'm getting the following error "certcontext is an invalid handle" and wondering if someone can shed some light.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
    string CertFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Resources\\cert.crt";
```

One presumes you meant to actually load CertFile at some point:

```
    string CertFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Resources\\cert.crt";
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertFile);
```

As it stands, you have a managed object which effectively represents the lack of having a certificate.